# Error when calling pig from oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am trying to read a specific file pattern using PIG action in Oozie WorkFlow :

**Oozie Workflow :**

```
<workflow-app>

   <fork>
        <path to ="subWorkflow1" />
        <path to ="subWorkflow2" />
   </fork>

<join>
</workflow-app>

**subWorkflow1.xml :**
<subworkflow>
<action>
<pig>
    Calling the pig script load_data_into_tbl.pig 
<params>{Namenode}</params>
<params>{input Path}</params>
</pig>
</action>
</subworkflow>
```

**pig script :**

```
load '${namenode}/data/filename*.log  -- This file  is in HDFS.  
.. . ... .
Store data into <Table_nm> using HCatStorer`

InputSource : /data/src_folder/20141029/filename*.log
```

First Attempt :

When I try to read the data from a folder from HDFS.Iam able to see PIG execution successful for first time. Rest of my execution is getting failed.

Second Attempt :

I found that When I try to rerun the OOzie with the same source file in folder(20141029) My  execution is getting failed.

Third Attempt :

Then , I tried rerunning the Workflow by renaming my source file in the folder (20141029). It works fine.

What could be the reason ?  Thanks in advance.

Error Logs :

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException.         org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationNotFoundException: Application with id 'application_1413868377323_35233' doesn't exist in RM.
at     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.getApplicationReport(ClientRMService.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.getApplicationReport(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationNotFoundException: Application with id 'application_1413868377323_35233' doesn't exist in RM.
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.getApplicationReport(ClientRMService.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.getApplicationReport(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:532)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:580)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:578)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobUsingCluster(JobClient.java:578)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getTaskReports(JobClient.java:633)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getMapTaskReports(JobClient.java:627)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.Launcher.getStats(Launcher.java:150)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:429)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1324)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1309)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1299)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:377)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:355)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:478)
at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:286)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:226)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)   
Failing            
Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this Issue.Its not actually an issue. Its the nature of Pig and there are some Tickets and working going on this Issue.Once data exists in a partition, you can't overwrite the data using Pig. Thats what the issue is.Thats why I am able to load successfully in my first attempt and not after that. Thanks !

Helpful Links :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat